# c# Windows form getting 'parameter not valid' exception when minimizing the form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms

I have a windows form with Bunifu Elipse Control Targeting Form1, when i clicks minimize button throwing an exception 'parameter is not valid'

same error happening when i change the FormSize to None (Boarder less form), and create a button (-) manually for minimize.
exception rises here

```
try
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
catch { }
```

Anyone help me from this bug! Thanks
Attaching Screenshots of bugs Here error dialogue screenshot

[image]

Comment: Does https://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-NET/TypeLoadException-crossed-native-managed-boundary/td-p/3136374 help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why all my exceptions messages now end with "crossed a native/managed boundary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182518/why-all-my-exceptions-messages-now-end-with-crossed-a-native-managed-boundary)

Comment: Uncheck VS(2010) -> Tools ->Options -> Debugging -> General -> Break When Exception Cross AppDomain/Managed .. Solves the problem!